# Excel INDEX MATCH to find exact location name from string text

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I have in my Excel workbook two tables:

1. In first table I have string text full sentence (in colunmn C) in many rows where is described in sentence some place names (some rows don't have those location names) and
2. in second table I have place names list (every place name have also geographical X (latitude) and Y (longitud) coordinates.

I want to search inside first table string text location names which have exact match to the `placename_table` list and show founded place name in first tabele column D. I tried this formula in column D, it almost working, but it finds first match of `placename_tabele` and it is not correct what was mean in first table string.

I use Excel 2013

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Placename_table; SMALL(IF(COUNTIF($C2;"*"&Placename_table&"*"); MATCH(ROW(ANIMI); ROW(Placename_table)); ""); COLUMNS($A$1:A1))); "-")
```

placename_tabels

[image]

Comment: Please put some sample data for clear understanding. Which version of excel you are using?

Comment: i use excel 2013 and added picture

Comment: Then what would be your output to D column? If there are multiple placement then what will be result? Like 3rd column for `Richard` have two `placement`

Comment: column D output have to be exact placename string according to placename_table. Rihhard second placename have to be in column E. In one column can be only one placename. After that the first tabel will be connected to GIS and placename points are shown on map.

Answer (score 0):

You may try `FILTERXML()` with index. Put below formula in `D2` cell then drag down and right.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE($C2," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[starts-with(., 'placement')]"),COLUMN(A$1)),"")
```

[image]

Comment: its not working, i have in Placement_table 5000 places and place names are sometimes inverted in a sentence,-> the Exact Palecment name should appear in column D. In your example sometime apear in col D first word of sentence.